# How to convert from LazyDynaBean to custom class

Tags: java, dynamic

I have to convert result of a LazyDynaBean class to MyCustom class. Whats the best way to convert result from LazyDynaBean , I see a way through BeanUtil class but its is not converting any of my own type of classes,

My Custom Class is like

```
public class Xyz {
  String name;
  Point point;
}

public class point {
  int x;
  int y; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is with nested classes (beans with properties that are in turn beans) you're out of luck with using `BeanUtilsBean.copyProperties()`. The [JavaDoc](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/v1.8.0/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtilsBean.html#copyProperties%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) does mention that it's intended for "shallow copying" only.

What you'll have to do is write your own "Converter" class to handle the conversion of the nested bean variable classes and stitch it all together yourself.

If you keep your top level bean limited on its use of non-bean member variables (i.e. push them down into another bean if there are many), your conversion code will at least be able to use `BeanUtilsBean.copyProperties()` for those beans that are "shallow".